# Java: Conversion from if statement to method

Tags: java

I'm having difficulty converting an `if` statement to different methods. I'm trying to convert it to 4 separate methods: add, sub, mul, and div, and it has to be stated in CMD, but I just can't do it somehow. I need help and thanks.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int first   = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    int second  = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
    int third   = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
    int forth   = Integer.parseInt(args[4]);

    if(args[0].equals("add")){
        if (second == 0 || forth == 0){
            System.out.println("Undividable by zero");
        } else if (second == forth){
            System.out.println(first + "/" + second + " + " + third + "/" + forth + " = " + (first + third) + "/" + forth);
        } else {
            System.out.println(first + "/" + second + " + " + third + "/" + forth + " = " + (first * forth + second * third) + "/" + (second * forth));
        }
    } else if (args[0].equals("sub")){
        if (second == 0 || forth == 0){
            System.out.println("Undividable by zero");
        } else if (second == forth){
            System.out.println(first + "/" + second + " - " + third + "/" + forth + " = " + (first + third) + "/" + forth);
        } else {
            System.out.println(first + "/" + second + " - " + third + "/" + forth + " = " + (first * forth - second * third) + "/" + (second * forth));
        }
    } else if (args[0].equals("mul")){
        if (second == 0 || forth == 0){
            System.out.println("Undividable by zero");
        } else {
           System.out.println(first + "/" + second + " * " + third + "/" + forth + " = " + (first * third ) + "/" + (second * forth));
        }
    } else if (args[0].equals("div")){
        if (second == 0 || forth == 0){
            System.out.println("Undividable by zero");
        } else  {
            System.out.println(first + "/" + second + " : " + third + "/" + forth + " = " + (first * forth) + "/" + (second * third));
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Recheck the code");
    }        
}
```

Comment: Why not make 4 such methods and call the right one depending on the value of `args[0]`?

Comment: @tilper That's exactly what he's trying to do.

Comment: Well this is my homework and the operator such as add, sub, mul, div has to be stated in CMD not in the method

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem, right, but it sounds like that's literally just a matter of moving code around, so I'm not sure I understand the question, unless OP is very new to coding.  I'm also not sure what "has to be stated in CMD" means.

Comment: Siddeshkanth, can you please clarify what you mean by "has to be stated in CMD"?

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want make one method 
public void this_is_your_method(int n){ ... }

I'm assuming the problem your having is because of System.out.println, when making a method you need to state what type it is you are trying to return since you want to print something you'd say void as in you don't want to print anything just print this and I wrote int n to make your job easier because writing all that code once is better than multiple times just change args[0] to args[n]

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

**Main.Class**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int first   = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    int second  = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
    int third   = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
    int forth   = Integer.parseInt(args[4]);

    if(args[0].equals("add")){
        add(first,second,third,forth);
    } ...
}

public static void add(int first, int second, int third, int forth) {
    if (second == 0 || forth == 0){
        System.out.println("Undividable by zero");
    } else if (second == forth){
        System.out.println(first + "/" + second + " + " + third + "/" + forth + " = " + (first + third) + "/" + forth);
    } else {
        System.out.println(first + "/" + second + " + " + third + "/" + forth + " = " + (first * forth + second * third) + "/" + (second * forth));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When there are lot of if then else you can also opt for switch-case.

Here is how you can modularize code into methods ...

I am also sharing how you can do it using lambda functions (java 8).

```
interface MathOperation {
    public void operate(int first, int second, int third, int forth);
}

public class StackOverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int first = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        int second = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        int third = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
        int forth = Integer.parseInt(args[4]);

        MathOperation addition = (a, b, c, d) -> { if (b == 0 || d == 0) System.out.println("Undividable by zero"); else if (b == d) System.out.println(a + "/" + b + " + " + c + "/" + d + " = " + (a + c) + "/" + d); else System.out.println(a + "/" + b + " + " + c + "/" + d + " = " + (a * d + b * c) + "/" + (b * d));};
        MathOperation subtraction = (a, b, c, d) -> { if (b == 0 || d == 0) System.out.println("Undividable by zero"); else if (b == d) System.out.println(a + "/" + b + " - " + c + "/" + d + " = " + (a + c) + "/" + d); else System.out.println(a + "/" + b + " - " + c + "/" + d + " = " + (a * d - b * c) + "/" + (b * d));};
        MathOperation multiplication = (a, b, c, d) -> { if (b == 0 || d == 0) System.out.println("Undividable by zero"); else System.out.println(a + "/" + b + " * " + c + "/" + d + " = " + (a * c) + "/" + (b * d));};
        MathOperation division = (a, b, c, d) -> { if (b == 0 || d == 0) System.out.println("Undividable by zero"); else System.out.println(a + "/" + b + " : " + c + "/" + d + " = " + (a * d) + "/" + (b * c));};

        switch(args[0]) {
            case "add" :
                add(first, second, third, forth);
                addition.operate(first, second, third, forth);
                break;
            case "sub":
                sub(first, second, third, forth);
                subtraction.operate(first, second, third, forth);
                break;
            case "div":
                div(first, second, third, forth);
                division.operate(first, second, third, forth);
                break;
            case "mul":
                multiply(first, second, third, forth);
                multiplication.operate(first, second, third, forth);
                break;
            default :
                System.out.println("Recheck the code");
        }
    }

    private static void multiply(int first, int second, int third, int forth) {
        if (second == 0 || forth == 0) {
            System.out.println("Undividable by zero");
        } else {
            System.out.println(first + "/" + second + " * " + third + "/" + forth + " = " + (first * third) + "/"
                    + (second * forth));
        }
    }

    private static void div(int first, int second, int third, int forth) {
        if (second == 0 || forth == 0) {
            System.out.println("Undividable by zero");
        } else {
            System.out.println(first + "/" + second + " : " + third + "/" + forth + " = " + (first * forth) + "/"
                    + (second * third));
        }
    }

    private static void sub(int first, int second, int third, int forth) {
        if (second == 0 || forth == 0) {
            System.out.println("Undividable by zero");
        } else if (second == forth) {
            System.out.println(
                    first + "/" + second + " - " + third + "/" + forth + " = " + (first + third) + "/" + forth);
        } else {
            System.out.println(first + "/" + second + " - " + third + "/" + forth + " = "
                    + (first * forth - second * third) + "/" + (second * forth));
        }
    }

    private static void add(int first, int second, int third, int forth) {
        if (second == 0 || forth == 0) {
            System.out.println("Undividable by zero");
        } else if (second == forth) {
            System.out.println(
                    first + "/" + second + " + " + third + "/" + forth + " = " + (first + third) + "/" + forth);
        } else {
            System.out.println(first + "/" + second + " + " + third + "/" + forth + " = "
                    + (first * forth + second * third) + "/" + (second * forth));
        }
    }
}
```